# Write a script which for any name given as an argument prints the list of paths to home directories of people with the name

Tags: bash, shell

I did it in this way and it's working. Is there another way to get the same result?

```
!/bin/bash

for name in $@

do

        awk -v n="$name" -F ':' 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};$5~n{print $6}' /etc/passwd | while read line

        do
                echo $line
        done
done
```

Comment: Fix your shebang.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new here. I hope it is okay right now

Comment: Your `while` loop is useless and can be removed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104616/how-to-print-matching-all-names-given-as-a-argument#comment109846887_62104616

Comment: It worked for me. Thank you very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it it in pure `bash`, using its regular expression matching:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS="|"; command eval 'name="$*"'
getent passwd | while IFS= read line; do
    IFS=: read -a fields <<<"$line"
    if [[ ${fields[4]} =~ $name ]]; then
    echo "${fields[5]}"
    fi
done
```

The `IFS="|"; command eval 'name="$*"'` line sets `name` to the command line arguments separated by pipes so they work as alternatives in the regular expression. (See [Bash FAQ 104](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/104) for details about the syntax of that line and alternatives.)

Example:

```
$ bash demo.sh "[Ss]ystemd" "[Rr]oot"
/root
/run/systemd
/run/systemd/netif
/run/systemd/resolve
/run/systemd
```