# How to print matching all names given as a argument?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a script for any name given as an argument and prints the list of paths
to home directories of people with the name. 
I am new at scripts. Is there any simple way to do this with `awk` or `egrep` command?

Example:

$ show names jakub anna (as an argument)

```
/home/users/jakubo
/home/students/j_luczka
/home/students/kubeusz
/home/students/jakub5z
/home/students/qwertinx
/home/users/lazinska
/home/students/annalaz
```

Here is the my friend's code but I have to write it from a different way and it has to be simple like this code

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in $@
do  
        awk -v n="$name" -F ':' 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};$5~n{print $6}' /etc/passwd  | while read line
        do
                echo $line
        done
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself

Comment: This might help: [Write a script which for any name given as an argument prints the list of paths to home directories of people with the name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62095582/3776858)

Comment: I saw this post but that code gave me different output and that code is really complicated for me. I want to do it with simple commands.

Comment: How for example `/home/students/j_luczka` matched to `names jakub anna` parameters?

Comment: Yes. When I type jakub anna as an argument program has to print everything with j-a-k-u-b letters. Here is my friend's code. I have to write it from a different way and it has to be that simple.

#loop over all names provided as arguments
for name in $@
do  
        awk -v n="$name" -F ':' 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1};$5~n{print $6}' /etc/passwd  | while read line
        do
                echo $line
        done
done

Comment: please update your question with the additional details you've provided in your comments; let's see ... it sounds like you need to match the `name` on a specific field in `/etc/passwd` so you should provide a sample `/etc/passwd`; next I'd suggest you place your sample code in the question ... then show 2 sets of output ... 1) the (wrong) output generated by your code and 2) the desired output

Comment: I added the sample code. You right I have to find the names on a /etc/passwd and I have to give these names as an argument. I gave the sample output in the question.Basically I am going to give names as an argument and find those names in the /etc/passwd thats all.

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired output, given the input data shown.

Comment: `for name in "$@"; do egrep -i "(^[^:]*${name}[^:]*)|(^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*${name}[^:]*)" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6; done`

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much for your comment

Comment: `^` = row start with / `:` = single character colon / `[^:]` = any character except colon / `*` = recurring at will / `|` = or / `-i` = ignore case / `-d` = delimiter / `-f` = column

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: searches in (1) username or (5) description https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/rhce-study-guide/etc-passwd-file-in-linux-explained-with-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Possible to use a simple `awk` script to look for matching names.

The list of names can be passed as a space separated list to awk, which will construct (in the BEGIN section) a combined pattern (e.g. '(names|jakub|anna)'). The pattern is used for testing the user name column ($5) of the password file.

```
#! /bin/sh
awk -v "L=$*" -F: '
BEGIN {
    name_pat = "(" gensub(" ", "|", "g", L) ")"
}
$5 ~ name_pat { print $6 } 
' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score -1):

Since at present the question as a whole is unclear, this is more of a long comment, and only a partial answer.

There is one easy simplification, since the sample code includes:

```
 ... | while read line
       do
             echo $line
       done
```

All of the code shown above after and including the `|` is needless, and does nothing, (like a [UUoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)), and should therefore be removed.  (Actually `echo $line` with an unquoted `$line` would remove formatting and repeated spaces, but that's not relevant to the task at hand, so we can say the code above does nothing.)